# How to mathematically choose values for a pi filter without knowing the cutoff frequency?

Tags: filter, low-pass, bridge-rectifier, ac-dc

I am trying to design an AC to DC converter. After the rectifier, I have a pi filter. I need to calculate my L and C values, but I don't know what the cutoff frequency is/how to find it! Any help is much appreciated. Below is an image of my circuit, although I have a 5 V 1 kHz sine wave as the input.

[image]

Comment: For conceptual purposes, consider breaking it up into a capacitor-input (C1) filter plus an LC output filter. That last part will have a very high-Q if you discount the inductor resistance. But you shouldn't. You'll want to select an inductor with an appropriate resistance to get the desired damping. But this means losses. So you need to know the load resistance. And the whole thing isn't very good if the load varies a lot. (It's not a good approach to widely varying loads.) Also, you may want to look up "power line filters" which are pi-filters but with a transformer and not an inductor.

Comment: You could consider the square root of your input frequency, since you seem to need the DC (e.g. if f=5 kHz then fp = sqrt(5000) = ~71 Hz). But, as jonk says, if your load is variable, you'll get peaking due to the increased Q and, worse, if your load is nonlinear with a negative incremental resistance, you may get oscillations. Can you provide more details about what you need it for, or what exactly your whole setup is?